# rrd graph configurate query

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

I am updating my RRD file with some counts...

For example:

```
time:       value:
12:00       120
12:05       135
12:10       154
12:20       144
12:25       0
12:30       23
13:35       36
```

here my RRD is updating as below logic:

```
((current value)-(previous value))/((current time)-(previous time))
```

eg.  `((135-120))/5 = 15`
but my problem is when it comes 0 the reading will be negative:

```
((0-144))/5
```

Here " 0 " value comes with system failure only( from where the data is fetched)..It must not display this reading graph.

How can I configure like when 0 comes it will not update the "RRD graph" (skip this reading `(0-144/5))` and next time  it will take reading like   `((23-0)/5)`    but not `(23-144/10)`

Answer (score 0):

When specifying the data sources when creating the RRD, you can specify which range of values is acceptable.

`DS:data_source:GAUGE:10:1:U` will only accept values above 1.
So if you get a 0 during an update, rrd will replace it with `unknown` and i assume it can find a way to discard it.